# ruby check "blank?" for multiple records in single line?

Tags: ruby

I have few records and need to check if all are `blank?` or not:

```
<% if new_sqft.blank? && executed_sqft.blank? && occupied_sqft.blank? && occ1_res.blank? && expire_res.blank? && termin_res.blank? && vacant_res.blank? && vacant1_res.blank? %>
```

how to check this in single line?

Answer (score 5):

```
[new_sqft, executed_sqft, occupied_sqft, occ1_res, expire_res, termin_res, vacant_res, vacant1_res].all?(&:blank?)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect these records are Rails records (because of the `blank?` method and the ERB tag). Rails returns `ActiveRecord` instances or `nil`. Since `nil` is *falsey*, you can omit `blank?` and just write:

```
<% if new_sqft && executed_sqft && occupied_sqft && occ1_res && expire_res && termin_res && vacant_res? && vacant1_res %>
```